# How to copy content of text file into another text file when a button clicked using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What I have done so far is a PHP code which is running when the page is refreshed:

```
<?php
    $pageRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';

    if($pageRefreshed) {
        $file01 = file_get_contents("file01.txt");
        $path = "file02.txt";
        $file02= file_get_contents($path);
        if ($file01!== $file02){
            file_put_contents($path, $file01);
        }
    }   
?>
```

but, I have an HTML button:

```
<button class="btn" id="refreshPanel" onclick="refresh_panel()">Refresh Panel</button>
```

and I want to copy the content of `file01` into `file02` if this button is clicked using pure javascript.

Both files and .html and .js files stored in the same folder in my computer.

Thanks for your help and time in advance!

Comment: Create a snippet, please.

Comment: How do you plan to run the JavaScript? Node.js? Classic ASP? Cordova?  Something else?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno. Thanks for your comment. I am new in Stack and it was a helpfull comment. I have added what I have done so far. I will appreciate your help!

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your comment. like: <script src="myscripts.js"></script> in .html file

Comment: @maziarser — Would you like it if any website you visited could include a bit of JavaScript and be able to read and write to any file on your hard disk?

Comment: @Quentin I did not get you! are you making fun or it is a real question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to write a file on client machine, You can't do this in any cross-browser way.

If you want to do something like this, you must pass the execution of these actions to server-side

Comment: So, I need to use ajax - for example?

Comment: @maziarser — No. Ajax lets you make HTTP requests. It doesn't let you modify files.

Comment: @Quentin is there any solution to get my issue being solved?